# Using Merge Keys in Fixtures and Unique Identifier Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, fixtures

I'm trying to use merge keys with a Rails YAML fixture. I have:

```
BOOK: &BOOK
  name: To Kill a Mocking Bird
  upc: 0215192786624

item_a:
  owner: user_a
  <<: *BOOK

item_b:
  owner: user_b
  <<: *BOOK
```

However, this causes Sqlite to complain on some of our development machines about duplicate identical primary keys. Any ideas? I checked and all computers are running 1.9.2 p180, and the problem happens only on about half our machines. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if this is due to an issue with merge keys not working in ruby 1.9.  More specifically the switch to the psych yaml parser:

http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/4300

Answer (score 0):

You would have to specify concrete ids on item_a and item_b.